# Shiro doesn't redirect to unauthorizedUrl w/invalid login - Shiro with Spring and Tiles

Tags: redirect, spring-mvc, tiles, shiro

I'm using Spring MVC, Tiles and Shiro.

This is how my unauthorizedUrl property is configured:
`<property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/unauthorized"/>`

My expectation is that when `MyAuthorizingRealm` finds invalid credentials, that Shiro will redirect to `/unauthorized`.

But, that doesn't happen for me on form submission. I have a login `@Controller` that is mapped to handle GET and POST actions for `/login`. For accesses to the url `/lists` the login form is displayed. So it seems to work in one case but not the other.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLoginFormView(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }

    // if this method doesn't exist a Post not supported exception is thrown
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handlePost() {
        return "this view doesn't exist";
    }
}
```

Even if I throw `AuthenticationException` from `MyAuthorizingRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo()` I still can't get Shiro to redirect to `/unauthorized`. It always ends up continuing with the filter chain and executes the POST method in the `@Controller`; and of course I expect a redirect instead.

Here is my `webapp-context.xml`:
http://pastebin.com/XZaCKqEC

And here is my `web.xml`:
http://pastebin.com/5H81Tm8A

Following is some TRACE log output from Shiro. Shiro works when you try to access `/lists`. But, when the login form is submitted the redirect to `/unauthorized` never happens. Note, the login submission is detected:
http://pastebin.com/ZEK3CTdJ

So, the login submission is detected but the original filter chain is executed anyway instead of redirecting to `/unauthorized`

I'm stumped. Many thanks for any help and if you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I think I see two problems:

1) Your pastebin for your spring xml does not show the SecurityManager
being configured with your realm.  I.e. it needs to look like this:

```
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="realm" ref="myRealm"/>
</bean>
```

2) You're setting up a Spring MVC controller to perform authentication, which implies you want to control when `subject.login` is called and not rely on Shiro's built-in FormAuthenticationFilter (`authc`).

If you do this, you will need to redefine the `authc` filter to be a
[PassThruAuthenticationFilter](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/PassThruAuthenticationFilter.html).

This allows the request to 'pass through' the filter chain to your
Login view/controller where you are responsible for calling
subject.login

You can do that in your spring.xml by setting the `filters` property and using `authc` as the name for your configured filter:

```
<bean id="passthruAuthcFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login"/>
</bean>

<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    ...
   <property name="filters">
       <util:map>
           <entry key="authc" value-ref="passthruAuthcFilter"/>
       </util:map>
   </property>
   ...
</bean>
```

Also, as a tip, you might want to use Shiro's WebUtils to redirect the end-user to the url they originally attempted before being redirected to login.  Shiro's `FormAuthenticationFilter` does this automatically, but when you perform the login yourself, you're responsible for doing this redirect if it is desired.

For example, in your `LoginController`'s handlePost method:

```
subject.login(authcToken);
WebUtils.redirectToSavedRequest(request, response, yourFallbackUrlIfThereIsntASavedRequest);
return null; //tells Spring MVC you've handled the response, and not to render a view
```

Comment: Sorry, my security manager is in my config; I just omitted it somehow from the post. It sounds like from what you are saying that it is not possible to use the Spring MVC facilities along with Shiro at the same time. In other words, I'd like to use the FormAuthenticationFilter and Spring MVC with Tiles all at the same time. If I use the FormAuthenticationFilter you are saying that I can't run it through the mvc controller so I lose quite a bit of functionality from the MVC framework. If that is the case, perhaps I do need to use the pass thru filter and do the handle login procedures myself.

Comment: Additionally, thanks for your feedback I really appreciate it.