# scheduling another page instead of home page while login

Tags: spring, url, shiro

I am working on a application having spring framework and implemented shiro filter for security.
Login url of my application login page is "localhost:8082/".
but I have changed the url manually "localhost:8082/socialProfile?by=Followers" at time of login.
What I was expecting, after login, instead of scheduling my application home page "http://localhost:8082/dashboard", It should schedule "socialProfile?by=Followers" page.
But it is scheduling "localhost:8082/dashboard" page.
Is there any way to get desired result ?

Comment: Can you share your configuration files?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've got answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303464/shiro-doesnt-redirect-to-unauthorizedurl-w-invalid-login-shiro-with-spring-an